# How to make my public Cocoa pods repo have documentation on cocoapods.org instead of directly redirecting to my github page?

Tags: swift, frameworks, swift3, cocoapods

I integrated my first library with cocoapods recently and have a full documentation readme on my github repo.

Unlike other pods, where if you search for them on cocoapods.org there is an expand button to see more information about the pod on the site, mine does not have it.Instead my own has three buttons [ Site, Docs, Spec] to the right of it, which all link to my github page.

What should i do to make the documentation accessible on cocoapods or do I have to wait for cocoapods to gather more information before they do that? Thanks!

The link to my library is https://cocoapods.org/?q=lang%3Aswift%20on%3Aios%20DLLocal. If it helps my library is coded using Swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at another library and found out that the Documentation parser cocoapods uses could not parse my information because it did not know my swift version.

The error given was:

> Error Parsing Pod
>
> Could not find Objective-C Classes.

The solution was to add a file in my github repo named ".swift-version"

With contents:

3.0

Which is the version of swift used in the program.